# Author archive doesn't work

Tags: archives, author

I'm trying to solve an issue on my website : www.jack35mm.fr

I didn't make the theme (just bought it), but the thing is : the author archive page doesn't work.

I mean : `http://www.jack35mm.fr/author/prescillia/` should display the posts of this author (which is the good author slug). Instead of this, it just redirect to the homepage (I tried with a non-correct author slug, it displays the 404).

I refreshed the permalinks, but now I'm kinda stuck, any ideas ?

FYI : it works on the theme preview : http://anthemes.net/themes/bou/box/author/anthemes/

Answer (score 0):

These things are fun because there are so many possibilities.
I'll start my series of answers here and you can accept it once we get it right.

First thing, your site is allowing directory listings -- this is bad for security -- but at the moment is helping me see what might be causing the problem :)

I can see you have the **redirection** plugin installed.

Could you deactivate that and try hitting your author URL then? That plugin has a nasty little default setting of doing extra work you may not want it to be doing -- and it can sometimes cause problems like this.

Example of Directory Listing: http://www.jack35mm.fr/wp-content/plugins/redirection/